# Scala: find diffs in lists with different structure

Tags: list, scala, diff

I need to find diffs and matching elements in two lists of *different* structure, such as`myBooks` and `top5books`, where first number is a book ID in both lists:

```
case class Book(id: Int, score: Int)

  val myBooks = Array(
    Book(117, 10),
    Book(34, 5),
    Book(85, 7),
    Book(55, 8),
    Book(21, 3)
  )

  val top5Books = Array(117,356,55,85,11)
```

Result should be in two lists:

```
val matched = Array(
    Book(117, 10),     
    Book(85, 7),
    Book(55, 8)
  )

val missed = Array(
    Book(34, 5),
    Book(21, 3)
  )
```

Can't use `diff` here because input arrays have different structure. What would be a nice, clean code to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use partition method:

```
val (matched, missed) = myBooks.partition(book => top5Books.contains(book.id))
```